# Cannot connect to mysql server ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, socket

i try to connect to mysql server but it gives me socket issue i have edited my.cnf from /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock to /home/mysql/mysql.sock 
Nb: the issue exist before moving mysql db file to the new directory.

```
[root@dc ~]# /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)


[root@dc ~]# ps aux | grep mysqld
root      8472  0.0  0.0 108216  1596 pts/2    S    10:18   0:00 /bin/sh  /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/home/mysql --socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-       file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedir=/usr --user=mysql
 mysql     8691  0.1  0.0 543468 47860 pts/2    Sl   10:18   0:00   /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/home/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock
root      8825  0.0  0.0 103356   852 pts/2    S+   10:20   0:00 grep mysqld
```

Mysqld directive under my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/home/mysql
socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the socket to the my.cnf in the client directive.

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /home/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld_safe]

socket                          = /home/mysql/mysql.sock
nice                            = 0

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                            = mysql
default-storage-engine          = InnoDB
pid-file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                          = /home/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: already added to my.cf 
[mysqld]
datadir=/home/mysql
socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Yes but you need to add it under the [mysql] directive as well, i'll update my comment for more detail

Comment: i can log with ssh now to mysql but when i use phpmyadmin it says: Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Comment: My guess is that PHPMyAdmin tries to connect using host based connection.
Add the socket to your phpmyadmin config:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/home/mysql/mysql.sock';
See: https://phpmyadmin-english-united-kingdom.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_socket

Comment: config.inc.php edited i added my new directory $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '/home/mysql/mysqld.sock'  and restarted httpd but is still not working

Answer (score 2):

Have you verified that the file /home/mysql/mysql.sock exists and is readable etc?

I've seen this in the past where there is right issues and the file doesn't get created or cannot be accessed.

Also, are there any errors in the logs when you do a '/etc/init.d/mysqld restart'*?

// Mike
*or whatever your OS wants for a restart of the daemon/service

Comment: /etc/init.d/mysqld restart correctly the out of mysqld.log:
151111 10:45:22 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
151111 10:45:22 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
151111 10:45:22 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
151111 10:45:22 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
151111 10:45:22 [ERROR] Native table

Comment: [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
151111 10:45:22 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
[ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances' has the wrong structure
151111 10:45:22 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has the wrong structure

Comment: @OmerStimpack it looks like you are using data from a different version of mysql than you are running.  The safe way to deal with this is do a dump with the version you were running before and then reload it into the new version.

Answer (score 1):

your ps output shows, that the socket of your mysqld is stored in:

/home/mysql/mysql.sock

but your mysql client tries the default of:

/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

So you could try:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u root -p -S /home/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: yes it works but how can i make my.cf recognize because i already add /home/mysql/mysql.sock in mysql config file because i cant access to phpmyadmin